# Is it possible to dynamically change video encoder parameters?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, hevc

I would like to know if I can dynamically change video encoder parameters for a given video?
For example I would like to start encoding a raw video in H.264/H.265 for the first 10s in 30fps and then, while the encoder is still working, change the fps to 20 for the rest of it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why yes, it is possible.

Comment: @szatmary could you point to some links to try them? Would this be possible with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is definitely possible provided the encoder you are using support dynamic parameter changing.

Comment: thank you for your comment, could you give me an example of such encoder or library if you know one?

Comment: @AndiDomi You can check MFX h264 encoder which is part of the intel media SDK. It supports dynamic parameter support(bitrate, resolution etc). Even libx264 supports dynamic parameters. Most encoder would support dynamically changing the encoder configurations without restarting the encoder. This may not be applicable for all the parameters but many use full parameters such as bitrate, resolution, FPS, intra interval etc can be controlled dynamically.

Comment: @prashanthns any online resources to start with on this? Would this be possible with ffmpeg?